# Conditionally divide and replace values in certain columns in R

Tags: r

Here is a sample of my **data** frame:

```
Site Plot Plot_size  Sp1  Sp2 Sp3 ... Sp108 
C   1     N/A         25    4   3       12
G   1     N/A         30   35   5       22
M   1     S           10   15   7       37
M   1     M            2    3   1        7
M   1     L            2    3   1        7
```

created using this **code**:

```
plots_cond <- trees_only %>%
  group_by(Site, Plot, Plot_size) %>%
  count(Species) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from= n)
```

Variables Sp1 ... Sp108 (columns 7:114) are species counts. I need to convert these count values to density per hectare (i.e. count value/hectares).

Hectare values differ according to Site, and Site + Plot_size for Site M:

C: 0.005

G: 7.5

MS: 1.6

MM: 8

ML: 16

I'm an extreme beginner and having trouble constructing an appropriate script to execute this. I believe I need to select columns 7:114 and divide by the associated hectare value if Site=='' or Site=='' +  Plot_size == '', but I don't know how to put this all together into a cohesive piece of code.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a small code chunk to produce the sample data you showed?

Comment: @geoff The code used to produce the sample is included my question

Answer (score 1):

You already used the `tidyverse` packages to prepare your dataset, therefore I will also use these packages.

First of all it might be helpful to create a column for hectors and use this column as a divisor later on. So I combined the Site and Plot_size column into one column with the `paste0` function. To ignore the unwanted <N/A> inside the Plot_size column, I used the `ifelse` function (<N/A> will be replaced with nothing). In a second step the hector codes (C, G, MS, MM, ML) will be replaced with your given hector values by the `case_when` function.

In a last step all species counts will be divided by the new hectar column and saved inside new columns with the suffix "_density" (`across` applys the same transformation to multiple columns).

**Data**

```
df <-  read.table(text = "Site Plot Plot_size  Sp1  Sp2 Sp3 
C   1     N/A         25    4   3 
G   1     N/A         30   35   5 
M   1     S           10   15   7 
M   1     M            2    3   1  
M   1     L            2    3   1 ",
                  stringsAsFactors =  F,
                  header = T)
```

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  # create a hectar combination of Site and Plot_size 
  mutate(Hectars = paste0(Site, ifelse(Plot_size == "N/A",
                                       "", Plot_size)),
         # replace the combination with numbers
         Hectars = case_when(Hectars == "C" ~ 0.005, 
                             Hectars == "G" ~ 7.5,
                             Hectars == "MS" ~ 1.6,
                             Hectars == "MM" ~ 8,
                             Hectars == "ML" ~ 16,
                             TRUE ~ NA_real_),
         # devide each species count by hectar 
         across(starts_with("Sp"), 
                ~ ./Hectars,
                .names = "{.col}_density"))
```

**Output**

```
  Site Plot Plot_size Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Hectars Sp1_density Sp2_density Sp3_density
1    C    1       N/A  25   4   3   0.005    5000.000  800.000000 600.0000000
2    G    1       N/A  30  35   5   7.500       4.000    4.666667   0.6666667
3    M    1         S  10  15   7   1.600       6.250    9.375000   4.3750000
4    M    1         M   2   3   1   8.000       0.250    0.375000   0.1250000
5    M    1         L   2   3   1  16.000       0.125    0.187500   0.0625000
```

Comment: Thanks so much @tamtam. Your code has successfully created the new density columns, but it hasn't divided the counts by the hec values, so there are no values in the new columns.

Comment: To further elaborate, it also doesn't appear to have combined Sites and Plot_size columns, replaced them with numbers, or divided the counts by the hec values. The Site and Plot_size columns remain unchanged.

Comment: This is altered version of your code I used:


density <- plots_cond %>% 

  mutate(Hec = paste0(Site, ifelse(Plot_size == "N/A", 

                                   "", Plot_size)), 

         Hec = case_when(Hec == "C" ~ 0.005, 

                         Hec == "G" ~ 7.5, 

                         Hec == "MS" ~ 1.6, 

                         Hec == "MM" ~ 8, 

                         Hec == "ML" ~ 16, 

                         TRUE ~ NA_real_), 

         across(c(7:113), 

         ~ ./Hec, 

         .names="{.col}_density"))